# ORA-01036; illegal variable name/number

Tags: php, sql, oracle, bind, ora-01036

I have the following insert query

```
include("ORCLconfig.php");

$addAclaim = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO claims_accidents (ID, CLAIM_NUMBER, DATE_OF, TIME, LOCATION, PURPOSE, WEATHER, ROAD, STREET_LIGHTS, SPEED_LIMIT, SPEED_PRIOR, SPEED_AT_MOMENT, AIRBAGS, AMBULANCE, SIGNALS, OCCUPANTS, DESCRIPTION, ROAD_LOCATION, PH_DRIVING, NAME_OF_DRIVER, DRIVER_DOB, DRIVER_OCCUPATION, MEDICAL_CONDITIONS, DRIVER_CONVICTIONS, AUTHORISED, DRIVER_ADDRESS1, DRIVER_ADDRESS2, DRIVER_ADDRESS3, DRIVER_ADDRESS4, DRIVER_POSTCODE, DRIVER_TELEPHONE, MATCH, V5_NUMBER, KEY_SETS, OS_FINANCE, VEHICLE_VALUE, VEHICLE_REG, VEHICLE_MAKE, VEHICLE_MODEL, NAMED_DRIVER, FATALITIES, DRIVEABLE) VALUES (null, :claimnum, :date_of_accident, :time_of_acc, :location_of_acc, :purpose, :weather, :road, :lights, :speedLimit, :speedPrior, :speedImpact, :airbags, :ambulance, :signals, :occupants , :accdesc, :street_of_acc :ph_driving, :driverName, :DRIVER_DOB, :driverOccupation, :driverMedical, :driverConvictions, :auth, :driverAddress1, :driverAddress2, :driverAddress3, :driverAddress4, :driverPostcode, :driverTelephone, :match, :v5number, :keySets, :osf, :vehicle_value, :vehicle_reg, :vehicle_make, :vehicle_model, :named, :fatal, :driveable)");

   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":claimnum", $claimnum);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":date_of_accident", $date_of_accident);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":time_of_acc", $time_of_acc);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":location_of_acc", $location_of_acc);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":purpose", $purpose);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":weather", $weather);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":road", $road);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":lights", $lights);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":speedLimit", $speedLimit);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":speedPrior", $speedPrior);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":speedImpact", $speedImpact);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":airbags", $airbags);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":ambulance", $ambulance);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":signals", $signals);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":occupants", $occupants);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":accdesc", $accdesc);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":street_of_acc", $street_of_acc);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":ph_driving", $ph_driving);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverName", $driverName);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":DRIVER_DOB", $DRIVER_DOB);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverOccupation", $driverOccupation);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverMedical", $driverMedical);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverConvictions", $driverConvictions);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":auth", $auth);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverAddress1", $driverAddress1);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverAddress2", $driverAddress2);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverAddress4", $driverAddress4);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverPostcode", $driverPostcode);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driverTelephone", $driverTelephone);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":match", $match);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":v5number", $v5number);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":keySets", $keySets);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":osf", $osf);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":vehicle_value", $vehicle_value);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":vehicle_reg", $vehicle_reg);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":vehicle_make", $vehicle_make);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":vehicle_model", $vehicle_model);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":named", $named);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":fatal", $fatal);
   oci_bind_by_name($addAclaim, ":driveable", $driveable);

   oci_execute($addAclaim, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
```

Everytime i try to run this query i get this error

```
oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I've done a bit of research and it's apparently it mean that one of the variables is not in the SQL statement. This is not the case for me, I've check the statement, the DB (which is oracle) table and all the bound variables and they all match.

The line number on the error would indicate that it is the $driveable variable. I did a check and this is being sent to the page fine.

Not sure where else to look so any help would be great.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You seem to have missed out a comma here,

```
:street_of_acc :ph_driving,
```

It should be,

```
:street_of_acc, :ph_driving,
```

Comment: HOW DID I MISS THAT!! it works perfectly now though :) thank you. i shall accept you answer in 9 minutes when it lets me :)

Comment: We only have two eyes and I am sure yours are boggled by now looking at this code over again and again... :D it happens.. glad all good.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @bonCodigos answer, you're not binding `:driverAddress3`

Comment: well spotted, i will add that one in too :)

Comment: That's a good catch too, but error was not generated due to *not binding* =)

Comment: @jampez77: I agree with bonCodigo, his answer is the more right one, so should be the accepted one.

Comment: I have to disagree because the code in my script actually had all the variables in. I must have deleted it by accident when formatting the question so the only error was the one @bonCodigo saw

Answer (score 0):

If you also have visual studio and you are using the details view. I suggest reconfiguring your data source. I was receiving the ORA-01036 error, and all I had to do was just reconfigure my SQL source, and it generated it properly for me. For me it was that I was not handling the original values properly when I was trying to update my data source.

I was also in Oracle.