# Error: DPI-1059: bind variables are not supported in DDL statements when call procedure using node-oracledb

Tags: oracle, ddl, node-oracledb

I created the stored procedure below in sql-developer :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_USER(
 t_username IN VARCHAR2, 
 t_password IN VARCHAR2,
 t_default_table IN VARCHAR2,
 t_quota IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
    m_statement VARCHAR2(1300);
    
    m_username VARCHAR2(30) := t_username;
    m_password VARCHAR2(30) := t_password;
    m_default_table VARCHAR2(30) := t_default_table;
    m_quota VARCHAR2(30) := t_quota;
    
BEGIN
    m_statement := 'create user ' || t_username || ' identified by ' || t_password;

    IF m_default_table != 'NULL' THEN
         m_statement := m_statement || ' DEFAULT TABLESPACE ' || m_default_table;
    END IF;

    IF m_quota != '0' AND m_default_table != 'NULL' THEN
        m_statement := m_statement || ' QUOTA ' || m_quota || 'M ON ' || m_default_table;
    END IF;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (m_statement);
END;
```

And this compiled with no errors. I also connected to oracle. Then i got a user data (**req.body**) like this:

```
{ username: 'a', password: 'a', tablespace: 'NULL', quota: '0' }
```

But when i execute the 'call' procedure query:

```
oracle.getConnection(
        {
            uuser : "AN",
            password: "AN123",
            connectString: "localhost:1521/orcl"
        },
        (t_err, t_connection) => {
            if(t_err){
                console.error(t_err);
                return;
            }
            t_connection.execute(
                `BEGIN 
                    createUser(:username, :password, :tablespace, :quota);
                END;`,
                {
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: req.body.password,
                    tablespace: req.body.tablespace,
                    quota: req.body.quota,
                    
                },
                (t_er, t_reslt) => {
                    if(t_er){
                        console.error(t_er);
                        return;
                    }
```

I received:

```
[Error: DPI-1059: bind variables are not supported in DDL statements] {
  errorNum: 0,
  offset: 0
}
```

I tried many ways to fix the procedure or the nodejs code but it didn't work. I'm very new to this topic. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please have a look at the example file of the documentation.
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlproc.js

Comment: @wolφi. I 've already seen that. All my parameters are IN parameters. So i just assign them the value in Req.body.x. Is that true according to the link you gave me?

Comment: Are there any way not using dll statement?

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with node-oracledb. You are right, the example says the default is in. However, I'd be tempted to specify the datatype and direction `username: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracle_db.BIND_IN}`. Besides, I'd simplify the example, for instance first creating a table with a hardcoded name, procedure without any parameters, then add a parameter for the table name, and work my way slowly towards your example. Please also check using different variable names, maybe one of them is a reserved key word.

Comment: There are two more possibilities: 1) In PL/SQL it's called CREATE_USER, the calling code uses createUser, but I expect this is a typo. 2)  Is there an extra comma in the line `quota: req.body.quota,` ?

Comment: @wolφi, i did what you told and got ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number. Btw, i deleted the extra comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code runs without error for me - once I fix the conflict between the name in the SQL statement `CREATE_USER` and the name in the JS file `createUser`.  Really make sure you are not calling some prior version of the PL/SQL package that does attempt to use bind variables in the CREATE USER statement (this was noted in comments).  As the error states: this usage is not supported by Oracle DB.  For example, you **cannot** do:

```
connection.execute(`create user :un identified by :pw`, ['cj2', 'cj2password']);
```

- This is a DDL statement
- It tries to use bind variables

And this isn't supported.  And it fails with DPI-1059.  Bind variables are used for data, not the text of statements.

Two other tips:

- Filter or sanitize your input values to avoid SQL Injection attacks
- Use the async/await style of programming (instead of callbacks) to save yourself some headaches.  See all the [node-oracledb examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0):

The error code `DPI-1059` looks unfamiliar, not like an Oracle error message. I've checked [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/src/njsErrors.c), they use `NJS-000` to `NJS-080`. Googling lead to Oracle's Database Programming Interface for C, which defines this error code in [dpiErrorMessages.h](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/master/src/dpiErrorMessages.h):

```
"DPI-1059: bind variables are not supported in DDL statements", // DPI_ERR_NO_BIND_VARS_IN_DDL
```

The constant `DPI_ERR_NO_BIND_VARS_IN_DDL` is only used once in the source code, in the file [dpiStmt.c](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/master/src/dpiStmt.c):

```
// attempt to improve message "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"
if (status < 0) {
    if (error->buffer->code == 1036) {
        if (stmt->statementType == DPI_STMT_TYPE_CREATE ||
                stmt->statementType == DPI_STMT_TYPE_DROP ||
                stmt->statementType == DPI_STMT_TYPE_ALTER)
            dpiError__set(error, error->buffer->action,
                    DPI_ERR_NO_BIND_VARS_IN_DDL);
    }
    return DPI_FAILURE;
}
```

As Oracle's error messages are very confusing, it is worth looking into `ORA-01036`, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480330/ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number)